# JQuery hide visible elements of the same data type after iteration length

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm trying to filter some elements with a button. At anytime there can't be any more than 2 elements. I need to filtering them by data type.

In this case I want to show the first 2 elements with data-type="news" and then hide the rest.

```
<div class="sq-list">
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="ava-tbig">
        <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
            <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
            <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
                <div class="ava-tnewsh1">Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="ava-tbig">
        <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="feature">
            <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
            <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
                <div class="ava-tnewsh1">Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="ava-tbig">
        <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="feature">
            <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
            <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
                <div class="ava-tnewsh1">Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <div class="ava-tbig">
        <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
            <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
            <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
                <div class="ava-tnewsh1">Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <div class="ava-tbig">
        <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
            <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
            <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
                <div class="ava-tnewsh1">Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.sq-filter-link--news').on('click', function(e){
    $('.sq-list > div').each(function(index){

        if($(this).children().children().data('type') ==  'news' && index >= 6) {
            $(this).hide();

        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to hide everything except 2 news, which 2? first 2 or last 2? What is el >= 6 doing??

Comment: Sorry I wanted to show the first 2 news. The jquery snippet was one of my attempts to do this.

Comment: `el >= 6` is definitely the deal breaker for your example.

Comment: Side note: `.each()` callback arguments are `index` and `element`... So `el` is the `index` here. That maybe confusing... While not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.each()` loop... You first have to find the element having a `data-type`... Because the loop is made from the a quite distant parent. Then compare the "type" and use a counter.

See comments in code.

```js
$('.sq-filter-link--news').on('click', function(e) {

  var maxNewsFilter = 2;
  var count = 0;
  
  // Lopping throught some parent <div>
  $('.sq-list > div').each(function() {

    // find the element having a data-type attribute
    var dataType = $(this).find("[data-type]");
    
    // Compare the value
    if (dataType.data("type") == 'news') {
    
      // Count this one, because it is a "news"
      count++;
      
      // If the count is higher than the max, hide!
      if (count > maxNewsFilter) {
        $(this).hide();  // $(this) is the "quite distant" parent to hide...
      }
    }
    
    // This else loop will hide the "feature" items
    else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Some demo basic styling... */
.ava-tbig {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
[data-type='news']{
  background-color:yellow;
}
[data-type='feature']{
  background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sq-filter-link--news">Filter News</button><br>
<br>
<div class="sq-list">
  <div>
    <div class="ava-tbig">
      <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
        <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
        <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
          <div class="ava-tnewsh1">(news) Title 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="ava-tbig">
      <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="feature">
        <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
        <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
          <div class="ava-tnewsh1">(feature) Title 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="ava-tbig">
      <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="feature">
        <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
        <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
          <div class="ava-tnewsh1">(feature) Title 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="ava-tbig">
      <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
        <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
        <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
          <div class="ava-tnewsh1">(news) Title 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="ava-tbig">
      <div class="ava-tnews" data-type="news">
        <div class="ava-tnewsimg" style="background: url('');"></div>
        <div class="ava-tnewstitle">
          <div class="ava-tnewsh1">(news) Title 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hide $(this) in the else part of if datatype == news.

Comment: Why an `else` ? It would hide the `feature` elements... That's not what OP wants.

Comment: Based on the comment I am under the impression that he just want to show first 2 news items.. everything else should be hidden. OP said: "At anytime there can't be any more than 2 elements".

Comment: @NawedKhan: I can't tell... Let's OP answer this. ;)

Comment: Yes @NawedKhan I just want to display the first 2 news elements. Thanks

Comment: Ok then... I edited with an `else` hiding all the "features" items.